# LARAVEL 5.4: PostTooLargeException in ValidatePostSize.php (line 24)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am currently developing an app with Laravel 5.4. I am using xampp and changed the php.ini, php.ini-development and php.ini-production files with the following configurations

```
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
memory_limit = 128M
```

I restarted Apache and my laravel development server but still, I get the error:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 14253688 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
>
> PostTooLargeException in ValidatePostSize.php (line 24)

I even restarted my PC and still not working. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read settings description prior changing it, because what you currently have makes little sense. File uploads goes via `POST` request, so value of `upload_max_filesize` must not be greater than `post_max_size` and you got opposite.

Another thing is, and this happens quite often, that you might have play with wrong `php.ini` file. This could be the reason why definitely smaller file than your limits cannot go thru. Also check, if you by any chance do not have some PHP configuration settings overridden in i.e. virtualhost configuration of your httpd. In general call `phpinfo()` and check if what it shows matches with what you have edited (incl. certain parameters).

Restarting PC is rather pointless. All you need to restart is httpd only, yet sometimes you need to shut httpd down and start it again (so two steps i.e. `/etc/init.d/apache stop && /etc/init.d/apache start`), and not just tell it to reload (`/etc/init.d/apache reload`). Finally, while PC/server power cycle ensures that all ends up restarted nonetheless, it's unnecessary to go to that extreme.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin Orlowski, it's working now.. I'll keep this in mind.. Thanks again! :)